# Are my Google Analytics ( 2 domains 1 site) duplicated or unique?

Tags: google-analytics, domains

We have recently built a new website with a new domain to replace an old website, and on the advice of our IT guys and web dev team have pointed both oldaddress.com's & newaddress.com's a records to the new website.

Now, they both share the same google analytics code (UA-12345-1) and as such we have two entries in the Google Analytics dashboard. The problem is I'm still fairly novice with GA and as the reports seem VERY similar (~25k pageviews for each domain), are these figures exclusively for that domain?

For example:

oldaddress.com 25,400 pageviews
newaddress.com 25,600 pageviews

Does this mean that in total for this website I have 51,000 pageviews.

Hope this is clear enough but let me know if anything needs clarifying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've set it up, `new.com` will be marked as duplicate, because `old.com`  had it first.
Add a `canonical` metatag to those sites to indicate the **one** you want.

If you want to move from `old.com` to `new.com` and the urls remain the same, use a `301-header` (I suggest in .htaccess, or else php) to show that you `permanently moved` your content. This will preserve pagerank. If you don't do this, you will have to rebuild all pagerank in the new domain.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that was the case. 301 redirects are something I'm looking to done very soon. In terms of the page view stats- for internal reporting purposes would the above example in the question interpret as 50k pageviews in total rather than just the 25k?

Comment: You can make something like a sub-code, another code under the same account, that can give you insights on what happends where, but I don;t now the details of that